# C++ Inheriting base Class Destructor

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I'm working on a game, where i have a derived player class that inherites from a Parent GameObject Class, What i want to accomplish is calling the base class destructor inside of the derived class destructor, can i do that?

Example:

```
// Base Class
class A
{
    public:

        // other code goes here...

        ~A();

    protected:
        int a;
}

// ...
// ...

// Base Class Destructor
A::~A()
{
    // sets a back to 0
    a = 0;
}

// Derived Class
class B : public A
{
    public:

        // other code goes here...

        ~B();
}

// Derived Class Methods
B::~B()
{
    // Calls for Base Class Destructor, How can i accomplish this
    A::~A();

}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that. It gets called automatically. Also, `A`'s destructor seems pointless, unless you leak a reference to `a` somehow.

Comment: But bear [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) in mind.

Comment: @juanchopanza so i don't need to create a derived class destructor?

Comment: With the code you have shown, you don't need to provide any destructors at all. The compiler generated ones will do the right thing.

Comment: @juanchopanza even if i have alot of initialized member propreties? Because i use the base class destructor to deallocate memory; i use textures and images in the game.

Comment: In general yes. It depends on the "properties". The internet is full of information about when you need to provide destructors.

Comment: @juanchopanza On more thing, about constructors, should i incude them even if don't have something to initialize?

Comment: Not really. Compiler will provide default constructor if it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent class' destructor is automatically called. Calling order of destructors is opposite to order of constructors; so that, it's ok to rely on parent class' fields in destructor of derived class.

You should better declare destructor as `virtual`. It's needed to determine correct destructor if you delete object of derived class through base class pointer.

Try adding trace output in destructors to ensure what calling order of destructors is.